How to properly deal with Urdu and Arabic characters in a Unity project?
In my Unity project I need to show text using the Urdu language inside text.
I tried to search for a font file including those glyphs and all I could find so far was "Noto Nastaliq Urdu".
Unfortunately, it's still failing at rendering the correct glyphs.
Here I show a scenario where first of all I grab the Urdu text from a Google Translate session where I asked the equivalent for the word "Setting":---

Then I selected a UI Text object inside the Unity Editor, and in the Inspector panel, where I already correctly set the Font property, I pasted that value coming from Google Translate inside the Text property:


As you can see, the pasted text shown both in the inspector panel and in the render, look different from what was shown on Google Translate.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Maybe I'm using the wrong font file? Maybe it's related to font ligatures? How can I correctly support the kind of text I'm trying to display?

Not familiar with Urdu, or Unity for that matter, but it looks like it is being rendered left-to-right instead of right-to-left!

Use TMP, rather than Unity's Text. Did you check the glyphs after font importing? It's not just drag & drop, sometimes I had to manually adjust settings on some fonts, even in latin alphabets. As for TMP, you'll have more control of LTR and RTL text there and cover @phuzi 's scenario as well.

I also used TMP with check glyphs but still it doesn't work. @TheNomad

Did you see 1138 glyphs in the Font Importer and the Font Asset? And used RTL before copy-pasting from Google Translate?

I tried This, But You Can see It's not Working & Where i found "1138 glyphs in the Font Importer" as you Mentioned @TheNomad

The empty squares means the glyphs were not imported.

There is a Filled Square I Checked it. @TheNomad

Everything goes good, as I can see, from your story. There is not any technical mistake. This is the way how Arabic languages are supposed to work.
They are read right-to-left (RTL). The text, you can observe in google translate, has reversed character indices. So far, when you copy it, you have reversed text in your clipboard buffer. If you take a close look on your text, you can notice, that your string in the editor is reversed string from the Google Translate.
To display this text correctly, you should have a UI component, that can display characters RTL. In the TextMeshPro you have to enable RTL option for all your text components, when they are displaying Arabic texts.


Look at This
The Font Displays in boxes, its not working.
How to apply to show text using the Urdu language inside Text Component only.
